# Is there a list of default template variables in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-context

I noticed that the django templates already have certain variables passed to it without you having to send any data. For instance, the 'user' variable can be called without sending any 'user' data to the template when rendering.

Is there somewhere where I can find a list of these 'default variables'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) setting contains the following values by default (in Django 1.6):

```
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
```

The above is a list of context processors. A context processor is a function which can add more variables to the context which is passed to each template.

For example, the variable `user` is added by `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"`.

Comment: Thanks, That helps a ton! I'm gonna look those up, but without looking those up, am I right to assume that I have some 'tags' from debug, media, static, and messages as default? (assuming they supply tags)?

Comment: @StevenRogers you need to read the documentation or otherwise the source code of those context processors. It's reasonable that the `auth` context processor adds the `user` variable but you'd still need to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

Django comes with a special Context class, django.template.RequestContext, that acts slightly differently than the normal django.template.Context. The first difference is that it takes an HttpRequest as its first argument. Go through the docs for more clearer Idea.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Answer (score 0):

Now in Django 4.1, the default context processors and template variables are listed at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#context-processors

Just for a quick reference:

| Context Processor | variables |
| --- | --- |
| django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth | user perms |
| django.template.context_processors.debug | debug sql_queries |
| django.template.context_processors.i18n | LANGUAGES LANGUAGE_BIDI LANGUAGE_CODE |
| django.template.context_processors.media | MEDIA_URL |
| django.template.context_processors.static | STATIC_URL |
| django.template.context_processors.csrf | csrf_token |
| django.template.context_processors.request | request |
| django.template.context_processors.tz | TIME_ZONE |
| django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages | messages DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS |